# Bound DataGridView is missing direction glyph on column click

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

Using standard winforms 
`DataGridView` in .net 2.0.

`DataGridView` is bound to the BindingSource.
BindingSource.DataSource is set to SortableBindingList.

Columns are created in my code and columns SortMode is set to **DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic.**

OnColumnHeaderClick I set multi-column sort with each column sort direction and glyph sorting order and refresh 
`DataGridView`.

`DataGridView` gets sorted correctly but the column sort direction glyphs are gone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support multi-column sorting in SortableBindingList I had to implement IBindingView and its methods as well.

Which means in my implementation of ApplySort(ListSortDescriptionCollection sorts)

needed to set IsSorted to true or false.